# How can i bind an json data with a key and Name for display

Tags: d3.js, c3

I have a situation to bind a json data with a key to plot a graph. But graph is plotting correctly but the name of the data is showing the same key. i need to avoid it .

How can i supply a name for my data. I have tried as follows but its seems not working.
Can any guys help one this.

```
data: {
                    //                        columns: [chartData],
                    json: data,
                    keys: {
                        value: [key]
                    },
                    type: chartType,
                    labels: true,                        
                    selection: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    names: {
                        data1: 'Some Name'                            
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in Advance :)
Kiran Gopal

Comment: use a datanest. Check here: http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/

Comment: Also, you may want to format your JSON a little bit differently and show what you actually want to achieve with your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `data1`, you should substitute the **value** of the variable `key`. Or you could construct the names value, like so

```
var names = {}
names[key] = 'Some Name'; 
var chart = c3.generate({
    ...
    names: names
  },
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ld2apq0g/